# Relationship probability and CDF (Poisson distribution)

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution

If $X_i, i = 1,...,n$, is Poisson with mean $1$, why is

$$\mathbb P\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \leq n\right\} = e^{-n}\sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{n^k}{k!}$$

I would appreciate some help/hint here... I recognise the right side of the equation as the CDF of Poisson. The left side, well, it is the probability that the sum is less than (or equal to) n, but why do that equals the CDF?

Comment: Because $\sum X_i$ has a Poisson distribution with parameter $n$ as the sum of $n$ iid Poisson distributions with parameter $1$ (you need independence).  More generally if $Y$ has a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$ and independently $Z$ has a Poisson distribution with parameter $\mu$ then $Y+Z$ has a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda+ \mu$

Comment: As comes forward in the comment of @Henry you should first realize that $Y:=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ has Poisson distribution. This with parameter: $$\mathbb EY=\mathbb E\sum_{i=1}^nX_i=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb EX_i=1+1+\cdots+1=n$$After that just work out $P(Y\leq n)=\sum_{k=0}^nP(Y=k)$.

Comment: Thanks! I guess $P(\sum X_i \leq n) = \sum P(X_i \leq n)$, but why?

Comment: I think I understand, now. The definition of the CDF, $F(n)$, is just $\sum_{x_i \leq n} p(x_i)$, and this is just another way to write $P(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \leq n)$... which is the left side, and the right side is the CDF...